# Python vigenere cipher going further than needed?

Tags: python, encryption, vigenere

I am attempting to create the vigenere cipher in python and there seems to be a problem. Here is my encryption code:

```
def encryption():
    plaintext=input("Please enter the message you wish to encode.")
    #This allows the user to enter the message they wish to encrypt.
    keyword=input("Please enter your keyword, preferably shorter than the plaintext.")
    #This allows the user to enter a keyword.
    encoded=""
    #This creates a string for the user to input the encrypted message to.
    while len(keyword)<len(plaintext):
        #This begins a while loop based on the fact that the length of the keyword is shorter than the length of the plaintext.
        keyword+=keyword
        #This repeats the keyword.
        if len(keyword)>len(plaintext):
            #This sees if the string length of the keyword is now longer than the string length of the plaintext.
            newkey=keyword[:len(plaintext)]
            #This cuts the string length of the keyword
    for c in range(len(plaintext)):
        char=ord(plaintext[c])
        temp=ord(keyword[c])
        newchar=char+temp
        if newchar>ord("Z"):
            newchar-=26
        newnewchar=chr(newchar)
        encoded+=newnewchar
    print(encoded)
```

I cannot seem to find the problem with it, however when I enter the plaintext "hello" and the keyword "hi" it come up with the following symbols: ¶´º»½. I think the addition in the for loop may be going too far.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand the ord() function, chr() is the inverse of ord()

```
 for i in range(300):
     print(str(i) + ' ' + chr(i))
```

If you don't use Unicode characters, you can use an alphabet string

```
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
for p,k in zip(plaintext,keyword): # you can directly iterate strings
    char = alphabet.index(p)
    temp = alphabet.index(k)
    newchar = char + temp
    if newchar > 25:
        newchar -= 25
    newchar = alphabet[newchar]
```

Answer (score 0):

I won't just solve the bug for you as there are many other things to improve here !
Put space around operators: `a=b` should be `a = b`, same with `+`, `-`, etc.

I find it better to use function params than `input`. You can always have a second function to get input and encrypt the input:

```
def encryption(plaintext, keyword):
    pass  # (do nothing)
```

I'll let you write the auxiliary function.

I, and most, usually put comments on the line above the corresponding code. Also, no need to write `This` every time, and imperative is generally preferred.

Now let's have a look at your `while` loop. The condition is `len(keyword) < len(plaintext)`, inside you check `len(keyword) > len(plaintext)`. When can that happen ? Only during the last iteration. So move the code out of the loop.
Also, what you do inside the `if` doesn't need an `if`:
`any_string[:len(any_string) + n] == any_string` (`n` being a positive `int`).
Plus you never use `newkey`!

So we can simplify the loop to:

```
# Begin a while loop based on the fact that the length of the keyword is
# shorter than the length of the plaintext.
while len(keyword) < len(plaintext):
    # Repeat the keyword.
    keyword += keyword

# Cut the string length of the keyword
keyword = keyword[:len(plaintext)]
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
# Do the operation once
txt_len = len(plaintext)
# Get a string just a bit longer than plaintext
# Otherwise we would have issues when plaintext is not a multiple
# of keyword
keyword *= txt_len // len(keyword) + 1
# Chop of the extra part
keyword = keyword[:txt_len]
```

Note that both will fail when `len(keyword) == 0`.

Now to the `for` loop:
You could use `zip`, as polku showed you, but I'll assume it's too complicated for now and keep the `range`.
You could also use the alphabet, but plain arithmetic can do the trick:
`alphabet.index(x) == ord(x) - ord('a')`, so in your code:

```
char = ord(plaintext[c]) - ord('a')
temp = ord(keyword[c]) - ord('a')
newchar = char + temp
# Or simply:
newchar = ord(plaintext[c]) + ord(keyword[c]) - 194  # 2 * ord('a')
```

If we ignore capital letters, we can safely substitute

```
if newchar > 25:
    newchar -= 25
# With
newchar %= 25
```

Finally:
`alphabet[i] == ord(i + ord('a'))`.

Here's all this put together:

```
def encryption(plaintext, keyword):
    # Do the operation once
    txt_len = len(plaintext)

    # Get a string just a bit longer than plaintext
    # Otherwise we would have issues when plaintext is not a multiple
    # of keyword
    keyword *= txt_len // len(keyword) + 1  # // is floor division
    # Chop of the extra characters (if there are any)
    keyword = keyword[:txt_len]

    # Create a string to store the encrypted message
    encoded = ""

    # Now you should change this to work with capital letters
    for c in range(txt_len):
        # 194 = 2 * ord('a')
        newchar = ord(plaintext[c]) + ord(keyword[c]) - 194
        newchar %= 25
        encoded += chr(newchar + 97)  # 97 = ord('a')

    return encoded


def encrypt_input():
    # This function should use input to get plaintext and keyword
    # Then use encryption with those strings and print the result
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the addition goes too far, because `ord` uses ASCII (where A is 65), while de Vigenère had A in the first position. You could subtract `ord('A')`. The code also assumes all characters are capital letters. Here's a variation that uses a few of Python's library functions to perform the task.

```
import string, itertools
def encrypt(text, key='N'):     # default to rot13 (:
    '''Performs a Vigenere cipher of given plaintext and key'''
    result=[]
    key=key.upper()
    for plain,shift in itertools.izip(text,itertools.cycle(key)):
        shiftindex=string.ascii_uppercase.index(shift)
        shiftto=(string.ascii_uppercase[shiftindex:] +
                 string.ascii_uppercase[:shiftindex])
        trans=string.maketrans(string.ascii_letters,
                               shiftto.lower()+shiftto)
        result.append(plain.translate(trans))
    return ''.join(result)
```

A more complete variant might only consume key for letters, but this will be fine if your strings only contain letters. The reason I stuck to the ASCII letters is because locale specific alphabets might not have the intended ordering nor a matching set of upper and lower case (for instance, german ß). It's also entirely possible to translate the key into a list of translation tables only once.